# How to import key pair to keystore in java and make key not exportable

Tags: java, keystore, private-key

I'm adding a key pair (private key and certificate) to windows key store in java. I need to make private key not exportable. Java code which does this makes private key exportable. How can I change this?

I didn't find any properties or attributes in which this can be changed. Keystore.store method gets LoadStoreParameter but it looks like it's about setting password for private key.

```
PrivateKey privateKey=...;
Certificate certificate=...;

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
keyStore.load(null);
keyStore.setKeyEntry("alias",privateKey,"".toCharArray(),new java.security.cert.Certificate[]{certificate});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to windows cryptographic services is managed by the SunMSCAPI provider. It provides a bridge between java JCE API and windows services. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI)

> The SunMSCAPI provider enables applications to use the standard JCA/JCE APIs to access the native cryptographic libraries, certificates stores and key containers on the Microsoft Windows platform. The SunMSCAPI provider itself does not contain cryptographic functionality, it is simply a conduit between the Java environment and the native cryptographic services on Windows.

The `WINDOWS-MY` keystore in SunMSCAPI uses the standard Java [KeyStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) API, and it does not define any type of "extractable" property, so I'm afraid you will not be able to establish it.